# AES-GCM with a fixed IV but a random "wrapped" key

Tags: aes, gcm, key-wrap

It is well-known that AES-GCM requires the IV to be unique for each message that is encrypted with the same key. If the IV ever repeats, with the same key, then AES-GCM fails catastrophically. Now, what if we used a *fixed* IV (e.g. all zeros), but instead used a new random AES key for each message? The random (per-message) AES key could be "wrapped" (e.g. via RFC 3394) using a *single* master key. The "wrapped" message key would then be prefixed to the AES-GCM-encrypted message. This allows the receiver to "unwrap" the message key, by using the master key, and then decrypt the AES-GCM-encrypted message as usual, with the fixed IV and message key.

Of course, now the random message key **must not** repeat, I suppose. But with a random 256-Bit AES key such repeats are **much** less likely than with a 96-Bit IV, right? Using a proper CRNG.

Is this a feasible concept?

Note: Much unlike AES-GCM-SIV, this does **not** require to process the entire message twice and, therefore, it does **not** require to buffer the entire message in memory.

This is slightly similar to but **not** a duplicate of, because they don't use key wrapping:
[AES CBC with unique key per message, but fixed IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48649/aes-cbc-with-unique-key-per-message-but-fixed-iv)

(here the key is **not** a pseudo-random function of the *message*)

Comment: Yeah sure, but AES key expansion is slow and high memory. This process will not perform well compared to alternatives.

Comment: What you're describing is essentially the KEK/DEK paradigm but with a fixed nonce. It can be done and [has](https://github.com/mimoo/eureka) been. However, whether this is sensible depends on the scenario and scale. If you're doing stream encryption and encrypting a message in chunks, this is a terrible idea. If you're AWS, you can't afford to rotate your key that frequently due to how much data is processed. You can also argue that you may as well randomly generate the nonce as well as rotating the key, or you could derive the key and nonce simultaneously using a KDF.

Comment: I see that having to initialize the AES key twice, instead of just once, is not ideal for performance. But why is it a "terrible idea" for stream encryption and encrypting a message in chunks? I think AES-GCM-SIV is bad in this scenario, because you would have to process the entire stream *twice* for "SIV" to work, i.e. you'd have to buffer/process the whole thing before you can send out the first chunk! With KEK/DEK, we need *two* AES key initializations at the start, but then we can encrypt or decrypt the chunks "on-the-fly" without the need to buffer everything. Right?

Comment: @pogoya9172 Because if you're encrypting in chunks with a fixed nonce, that means rekeying for every chunk. The chunk size is usually 16, 32, 64 KiB, which is a lot of rekeying. Then the chunks are completely independent of each other, so if you're not careful, they can be rearranged, chunks can be dropped, etc. AES-GCM-SIV is not as inefficient as people seem to think it is, and that's the price you must pay for misuse resistance.

Comment: I don't think I *must* re-key after every chunk. AES-GCM can encrypt a bit-stream of arbitrary length, with a *single* key+IV instance. And, unlike AES-GCM-SIV, standard AES-GCM does **not** need to be provided with the *complete* input message (which could be huge!) before any output data is produced. Instead, we can feed it with small chunks of input data. And, each time we feed in $n$ bits, we get back an equally sized chunk of encrypted data, which can already be transmitted – even if *not* all input data is yet generated/known. The "auth tag" is generated/sent after the last chunk.

Comment: AES-GCM has a limit on the size of the message that can be encrypted ([64 GiB](https://soatok.blog/2020/12/24/cryptographic-wear-out-for-symmetric-encryption/)). Furthermore, AEAD APIs in cryptographic libraries don't work like that; you pass the entire message. Stream/chunked/session encryption also means you get [many](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/189) tags, not just one. You want to detect tampered chunks early rather than having to process the entire (unchunked) ciphertext. Fixing the nonce doesn't make sense in this scenario. It makes more sense for key wrapping.

Comment: I'm mostly familiar with Java/BouncyCastle API. And, with that API, we call `init()` ***once*** to set up the key plus IV. Then we call `update()` (or `updateAAD()`) function ***in a loop***, until all chunks of input data (or "associated" data) have been processed. Those are "$n$ bytes in, $n$ bytes out" functions, so we get chunks of encrypted data back, already before all input data was encrypted. Finally, we call `doFinal()` to handle the *last* chunk of input data. In case of AEAD (e.g. AES-GCM) the `doFinal()` appends the "auth tag" to the last chunk of output (encrypted) data.

Comment: Yes, there are exceptions to passing in the entire message, but there are also lots of APIs that are not like what you describe. For example, libsodium, Monocypher, and the .NET System.Security.Cryptography. And that does not invalidate my other remarks. What you're describing is not the same as stream/session encryption. Anyhow, your question has been answered by two people.